# Finding empty records in Mongodb using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongo database storing information about some weather stations. For example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae052a739027d186162ed50"), 
    "src_id" : NumberInt(55844), 
    "Name" : "ABERDEEN: NIGG HEAD WORKS", 
    "Area" : "ABERDEENSHIRE", 
    "Area type" : "COUNTY", 
    "Station start date" : ISODate("1997-03-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "Station end date" : null, 
    "Postcode" : "AB12", 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -2.06163, 
            57.1318
        ]
    }
}
```

In order to find the records with empty `"Station end date"` I do the following query in Mongodb and it works:

```
db.MIDAS_stations.find({
    "Station end date" : null
})
```

However, using `pymongo` I tried without success. In theory, this should work, but it doesn't:

```
returned_location = db.MIDAS_stations.find(
    {
        "Station end date" : None
    }
)
print(list(returned_location))
```

It always returns an empty result. Any ideas of how can this be sorted?

Comment: Works for me. Just inserted your document and even used the same collection name and copied the query from here. Returns the document without a problem. You are probably in the wrong database namespace.

Comment: I just noticed I was connected to the same database but with different content. The code is working fine. I should sleep more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works just fine. The problem was that I was connected to a different database, containing the data before it was prepared. Shame on me.